# using like clause entity framework core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use like clues in Entity Framework Core 3.1. My code like this:

```
List<NormalAccount> normalAccounts = _context.Accounts.OfType<NormalAccount>()
    .Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.AccountName,mysearchtext))
    .Skip(offset)
    .Take(limit)
    .ToList();
```

I get an exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions, System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

What is the problem?